# Word for someone who thinks they are doing much better than they are

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the one word substitution for "one who thinks that he is doing something great but in reality there is no progress in his life"..?

Comment: There is no such word in Merrium Webster. Could you please suggest any other word?

Comment: Nice joke sir.. :)

Comment: [self-aggrandizing](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/self-aggrandizing), [over-optimistic](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/over-optimistic) [**delusionist**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/delusionist)

Comment: That was a typing mistake. Sorry for that.

Comment: Hinted at by @FumbleFingers and ventsyv: [*self-delusional*](https://www.wordnik.com/words/self-delusional)

Comment: Some tangentially related terms are [megalomania](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/megalomania) and [narcissism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissism).

Answer (score 5):

**Delusional**

> adjective
>
> 1. *having false or unrealistic beliefs or opinions*
>      Senators who think they will get agreement on a comprehensive tax bill are delusional.
> 2. (Psychiatry) *maintaining fixed false beliefs even when confronted with facts, usually as a result of mental illness*
>      He was so delusional and paranoid that he thought everybody was conspiring against him.

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/delusional)

Comment: Please remember that when you quote text from somewhere, you have to include your source (in this case the dictionary you copied the definition from), with both name and link; otherwise, your quote is, according to StackExchange guidelines, considered plagiarism, and your answer will be deleted by the moderators. (Also remember that indenting text four spaces is meant for _code_, not quoted text; you start each paragraph with “>” to quote text instead.) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch, bit of a harsh definition. Perhaps:

> **Idler**: A person who passes time without being engaged in purposeful
>   activity
>
> **Laggard**: A person who makes slow progress and falls behind others.

Or because it's fun to say, a:

> **Ne'er-do-well**: A person who is ineffectual, idle, unsuccessful, or completely lacking in merit.

I'd also probably put "delusional" infront of these as delusion by itself doesn't mean the person is going no-where. I mean, Donald Trump is fairly delusional and he's a billionaire running for the U.S. presidency. ;)

Comment: It’s gonna be tough to find both of the ideas that the OP wants in just one noun, but I agree that ‘Ne'er-do-well’ is fun to say! Maybe combining it with another fun word would work: He’s such “a vainglorious ne'er-do-well!”

Comment: @PapaPoule Oh, I like that one! How about narcissistic ne'er-do-well. Just the right amount of syllables for a children's clapping game.

Comment: To me, none  of these really convey both OP's requirements that it must describe someone who performs poorly AND thinks highly of themselves.

Comment: I agree with Kristina

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider *[anosognosia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anosognosia)*, or, a little less clinical, *[the Dunning-Kruger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect)*:

> In 2011, David Dunning wrote about his observations that people with
>   substantial, measurable deficits in their knowledge or expertise lack
>   the ability to recognize those deficits and, therefore, despite
>   potentially making error after error, tend to think they are
>   performing competently when they are not: "In short, those who are
>   incompetent, for lack of a better term, should have little insight
>   into their incompetence—an assertion that has come to be known as the
>   Dunning–Kruger effect".[2] In 2014, Dunning and Helzer described how
>   the Dunning–Kruger effect "suggests that poor performers are not in a
>   position to recognize the shortcomings in their performance".